# Problem Copying Uploaded Files to a New Yii2 Model

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm working on a Yii2 application and have encountered an issue when attempting to duplicate a model along with its uploaded files. I'm using Yii2's UploadedFile for file uploads. The challenge is that the uploaded files (imageFiles) are not being successfully copied to the new model. Here's my code:

```
public function actionDuplicate($id)
{
    $existingModel = $this->findModel($id);
    $model = new Task();
    
    // Copy attributes from the existing model
    $model->attributes = $existingModel->attributes;

    // Manually copy the imageFiles property if it exists
    if (isset($existingModel->imageFiles) && is_array($existingModel->imageFiles)) {
        $model->imageFiles = [];
        foreach ($existingModel->imageFiles as $file) {
            $model->imageFiles[] = $file;
        }
    }

    // Reset primary key
    $model->id = null;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        // renders view
    } else {
        // Render the create form with the new model
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The code copies most attributes correctly, but the imageFiles property is not being included in the new model. I've double-checked that the imageFiles property exists in the source model ($existingModel) and that it's an array. What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure that the imageFiles are correctly copied to the new model

**EDIT :**
The imageFiles attribute is an array of files declared inside the Model, and it's handled with the following upload function:

```
public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $path = Yii::getAlias('@doc_attivita') . "/" . $this->id;
            FileHelper::createDirectory($path, $mode = 0775, $recursive = true);
            foreach ($this->imageFiles as $file) {
                $file->saveAs($path . "/" . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: My guess is that `imageFiles` property is not regular model attribute. It's probably relation field or something populated by model's internal logic. We can't really help with solution without knowing more about how is that field defined or populated in model.

Comment: @MichalHynčica yes, indeed, it's an array of files declared inside the model : 
/**
     * var UploadedFile[]
     */
    public $imageFiles;

Comment: @MichalHynčica I just edited the post, could you please give it a check?

Comment: The problem is that you can't use `yii\web\UploadedFile` while copying existing model. That class can only work with files that were just uploaded in the current POST request. If you want to copy existing files you have to do following: 1. copy the model without files. 2. copy related files. 3. link the copy of files to new model created in step one. Specific implementation of these steps depends on how exactly are files stored and linked in your implementation.